# Unable to fetch file content from nested directory using Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to read the files content from directory using node.js. But that folder again might had some nested directory so I need to read each file present inside root directory. I am explaining my code below.

```
checkDirectory = async (path) => {
    let fileArr = [];
    let flag = 0;

    if (!_.isEmpty(path)) {
        fs.readdirSync(`${path}`).forEach(f1 => {
            fs.lstat(`${path}/${f1}`, (err, stat) => {
                if (!err) {
                    if (stat.isFile()) {
                        flag = 1;
                        let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(`${path}/${f1}`, {
                            encoding: 'utf8',
                            flag: 'r'
                        });
                        fileArr.push({
                            rawContent: rawdata,
                            fileName: f1
                        });
                    }
                    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                        flag = 0;
                        const fullPath = `${path}/${f1}`;
                        checkDirectory(fullPath);
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
    if (falg === 1) {
        return fileArr;
    }
}
let dataArr = [];
fs.readdirSync(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads}`).forEach(f => {
    fs.lstat(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads/${f}`, (err, stat) => {
        if (!err) {
            if (stat.isFile()) {
                let outputObj = {};
                let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads/${f}`, {
                    encoding: 'utf8',
                    flag: 'r'
                });
                if (!_.isEmpty(rawdata)) {
                    const contentToBase64 = Buffer.from(rawdata, "utf8").toString('base64');
                    outputObj = {
                        fileName: f,
                        fileData: contentToBase64
                    }
                    dataArr.push(outputObj);
                }
            }
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                const fullPath = `${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads/${f}`;
                let fileContentArr = checkDirectory(fullPath);
                for (let e of fileContentArr) {
                    if (!_.isEmpty(e.rawContent)) {
                        const contentToBase64 = Buffer.from(e.rawContent, "utf8").toString('base64');
                        outputObj = {
                            fileName: e.fileName,
                            fileData: contentToBase64
                        }
                        dataArr.push(outputObj);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
}
console.log('dataArr', dataArr);
```

Here I am trying to read the file content from `uploads` folder. When I am executing this code its throwing the following error.

**Error:**

```
dataArr []
/app/controller/usecaseWorkflowCtrl.js:135
                                    for(let e of fileContentArr) {
                                                 ^

TypeError: fileContentArr is not iterable
```

Here also I am checking if any nested folder is present inside `uploads` folder and reading all the files from those nested directory. `checkDirectory` method is used to read files from nested directory.

I need to read all the files from `uploads` directory and push them to `dataArr` . After reading all the files then `console.log('dataArr', dataArr);` should execute. As per my current code this console message is executing from beginning and throwing some error. Please help me to resolve this error and execute the script as per my expected result.

Comment: Why is there no return in `checkDirectory(fullPath);` ? Shouldn't it be `return checkDirectory(fullPath);`

Answer (score 0):

Wait for checkDirectory before using it. You can accompish this by turning the function into a promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise. You can have somethin like this:

```
checkDirectory = (path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let fileArr = [];
        let flag = 0;

        if (!_.isEmpty(path)) {
            fs.readdirSync(`${path}`).forEach(f1 => {
                fs.lstat(`${path}/${f1}`, (err, stat) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        if (stat.isFile()) {
                            flag = 1;
                            let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(`${path}/${f1}`, {
                                encoding: 'utf8',
                                flag: 'r'
                            });
                            fileArr.push({
                                rawContent: rawdata,
                                fileName: f1
                            });
                        }
                        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                            flag = 0;
                            const fullPath = `${path}/${f1}`;
                            checkDirectory(fullPath);
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        }
        if (falg === 1) { // why do you need this
            return resolve(fileArr);
        }
    });
}
```

Then use it like:

```
let fileContentArr = await checkDirectory(fullPath);
```